# Defining query parameters for basic CRUD operations in Loopback

Tags: json, swagger, loopbackjs, swagger-2.0

We are using Loopback successfully so far, but we want to add query params to our API documentation.

In our swagger.json file, we might have something that looks like =>

```
    {
      "swagger": "2.0",
      "info": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "poc-discovery"
      },
      "basePath": "/api",
      "paths": {
        "/Users/{id}/accessTokens/{fk}": {
          "get": {
            "tags": [
              "User"
            ],
            "summary": "Find a related item by id for accessTokens.",
            "operationId": "User.prototype.__findById__accessTokens",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "fk",
                "in": "path",
                "description": "Foreign key for accessTokens",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string",
                "format": "JSON"
              },
              {
                "name": "id",
                "in": "path",
                "description": "User id",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string",
                "format": "JSON"
              },
               {  
                  "name":"searchText",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"The Product that needs to be fetched",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"ctrCode",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"The Product locale needs to be fetched. Example=en-GB, fr-FR, etc.",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               },
            ],
```

I am 99% certain the `swagger.json` information gets generated dynamically via information from the .json files in the `/server/models` directory.

I am hoping that I can add the query params that we accept for each model in those .json files. What I want to avoid is having to modify swagger.json directly.

What is the best approach to add our query params so that they show up in our docs? Very confused as to how to best approach this.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of tinkering, I'm afraid there is not a straight forward way to achieve this as the `swagger` spec generated here is representation of remoting metadata for model methods along with Model data from `model.json` files.
Thus, updating remoting metadata for built-in model methods would be challenging and it might not be fully supported by method implementations.

Right approach, IMO, here is to:
- create a [remoteMethod](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-methods.html) wrapper around built-in method for which you want additional  params to be injected with requried `http` mapping data.
- And, disable the REST end-point for the built-in method using 
`MyModel.disableRemoteMethod(<methodName>, <isStatic>)`.

Comment: there is *not* a straight forward way...?

Comment: One more thing: if you endup writing remoteMethod, you will need to handle extra parameters in remote method implementation and pass the correct arguments as expected by model method in order to get the expected outcome.